# if and else are both true

Tags: php, conditional-statements, if-statement

Sorry for this crazy question but it seems to be odd!
I have a code:

```
if(isset($_GET['tablename'])){
    $tablename=$_GET['tablename'];
    var_dump($tablename);
    echo 'Table is set <br/>';
    if($tablename="product"){
        echo 'Table is product <br/>';
    };
    if($tablename="demanded"){
        echo 'Table is demanded <br/>';
    };
};
```

and this is what I see on display:

> string 'demanded' (length=8)
>   Table is set
>   Table is product
>   Table is demanded

please help
I want to run sub queries depending on table value (product or demanded)

Comment: You're assigning value not comparing check mobius and also blaster answer

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You should use `==` to make the comparison, not a single `=`

Answer (score 3):

Use `elseif` with `==` or `===` (for strict comparison):

```
if($tablename == "product"){
    echo 'Table is product <br/>';
}
elseif($tablename == "demanded"){
    echo 'Table is demanded <br/>';
}
```

This is how your code should be:

```
if(isset($_GET['tablename'])){
    $tablename=$_GET['tablename'];
    var_dump($tablename);
    echo 'Table is set <br/>';

    if($tablename === "product"){
        echo 'Table is product <br/>';
    }
    elseif($tablename === "demanded"){
        echo 'Table is demanded <br/>';
    }
}
```

You also had `;` at the end of ending curly brace `}` which isn't needed, fixed also in above code.

### Errors You Had

- You were using `=` instead of `==` or `===`
- You had `;` before ending curly braces `}` for conditions

### Improvements You Can Make

- Use `===` instead of `==` since you know already are comparing to string
- In your code, using `elseif` rather than individual `if` conditions is syntactically more correct
- Never use `$_GET['tablename']` for production code if those table names are used to interact with database otherwise your code doesn't offer security

Comment: for the record: this answer is in its intend good, but syntactical wrong: there can't be a `;` between `}` and `elseif..`

Answer (score 0):

For comparison of strings use

```
  strcmp(string1,string2);   //return 0 when both strings are equal
```

Answer (score 0):

Use like this

```
 if(isset($_GET['tablename'])){
        $tablename=$_GET['tablename'];
        var_dump($tablename);
        echo 'Table is set <br/>';
        if($tablename=="product"){
            echo 'Table is product <br/>';
        };
        if($tablename=="demanded"){
            echo 'Table is demanded <br/>';
        };
    };
```